# Why is CSS style background picture not working

Tags: css

I am creating a website however the CSS style is not working although I took the code from YouTube and checked it 1 million times!

this is the CSS style

[image]

Comment: Please provide a working snippet.

Comment: it should be in one line. like: `background-image: linear-gradient...`

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imagesofcode

Answer (score 1):

if your image file isn't in the folder that your style.css file is so you must change the image url in background-image style

Answer (score 1):

The image path inside `url(img/UAE.jpg)` means:

- find a folder named `img` in the same folder as this css file
- and then find a file named `UAE.jpg` inside of it.

Make sure that your file path is correct. Otherwise give absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Check where your `img` folder is. If it is in the same folder where your `.css` file is, then your code should be `background-image: url(img/UAE.jpg);`

Otherwise, if you have a folder structure like below, you need to target that folder with following code: `background-image: url(../img/UAE.jpg);`

[image: Image example]

Just place `../` before `img`.

Answer (score 0):

try using `background` instead of `background-image`.

Docs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/background
- https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm not supposed to ask for clarification in answers, but I can't post comments and it's hard to answer this question without knowing what is going wrong. So here's a list of some problems that might be occurring.

There are three (potential) problems here:

1. `linear-gradient` is on two lines and should be on one. If you aren't seeing a background image, that's why.
2. If the `img` folder is not in the same folder as `style.css`, you should use `/img/UAE.jpg` instead of `img/UAE.jpg`. If the image isn't appearing, that's why.
3. The one that people haven't mentioned before is that the `linear-gradient` property is using the same color for both its values. If you're only seeing one color and expected two, that's why.